# Should I use "do it" or "do so" in the following example?

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

I found a good explanation [here](https://www.beatthegmat.com/to-do-so-v-s-to-do-it-t104348.html). Basically, you use "do it" when you are referring to a noun and "do so" when you are referring to an action or clause.

So by this logic, the following:

> I won't ask to meet face-to-face again. We can do it/do so whenever you feel
> like it."

The correct choice is "do so" since it's referring to "meet face-to-face," not to a pronoun?

Comment: While that may be technically correct, in casual conversation either is perfectly fine and "do it" is arguably more common

Comment: I don't think I make the distinction myself. BTW, I would replace your second sentence with just "We can wait until you feel like it."

Comment: The Picard way would use both *it* and *so*: Make it so ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that defining 'it' too strictly is causing some confusion. The word 'it' has a whole range of functions, including to refer to facts, events, or situations. In the explanation you linked, the author claims that the sentence

> Joe needs to prepare a list of all the projects assigned this year and **to do it** he needs to meet all the teachers.

is incorrect because 'it' is replacing an action (not a noun). However, I'd be surprised if any native speaker would consider this unnatural or ungrammatical.  I do agree with the point that only 'do it' should be used in the case of a noun ('the project'), but I think that do it/do so are interchangeable in the case of an action ('prepare the project').

> I need to plan out the month's schedule, but to **do it / do so** I have to find out my work rota.

Comment: I agree with this. In casual speech, "it" can be used to mean "that whole thing I just talked about at length" without strictly referencing an individual verb or noun.  (Of course, if you're taking a language test, you have to be super-technical and say "it" is wrong.)